# How to use Regex_Like for this case?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle-apex, regexp-like

I have a field named `Order_ID` from table `Order`.

when  value of `Order_ID` starts with numeric value then it should exclude those records, otherwise it should include those records in the report.

For example: if the `Order_ID` starts with a value **1ABC** it should exclude that record from report .

If `Order_ID` has a value **A1BC** it should not exclude those records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gayatri,
put following in report where condition

`WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(Order_ID, '^[0-9]');`

report it exclude entries start with numbers and contains values start with Alphabetics only.

Hopes this helps.

Comment: Thank you all for helping.The logic works perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm#SQLRF00501

for your particular case it's going to be something like

```
SELECT ... WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (Order_ID, '^[a-zA-Z]+.*$');
```

Comment: but also I'd like to mention that using regular expressions may dramatically slow down your performance on a big datasets. If you need to run queries like that it's very possible that it's something wrong with your design, or maybe you need some additional indexer in from of your database.

Answer (score 0):

This is the regex statement 
`(Order_ID, "[A-Z]{1}\d{1}[A-Z]{3}")`